# display output from a rake task called by SSHKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sshkit

I'd like to be able to output information from a rake task called by SSHKit but I can't see how to do it.

Say I have the following rake tasks:

```
require 'sshkit/dsl'

task :hello => :environment do  
  puts "Hello world"
end

task :sshkit_hello => :environment do  
  run_locally do
    rake "hello"  
  end
end
```

If I run the :hello task on it's own I see the "hello world" statement. However, call it from the sshkit task and I just get SSHKit info. How can I write out info from that first rake task that will appear when called from SSHKit?

```
rake hello
=> Hello world

rake sshkit_hello
=> INFO [f0857f14] Running /usr/bin/env rake hello on 
=> INFO [f0857f14] Finished in 6.107 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

EDIT1:

I've found that you can add the following to get basic terminal output:

```
SSHKit.config.output = $stdout
```

but, again, the information outputted is the same - it tells you that it's running 'rake hello' but not the output from 'rake hello'.

```
rake sshkit_hello
=> rake hello
```

Comment: It's in the readme? https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#output-handling

Comment: I've been through that and don't get how it works. Simply adding SSHKit.config.output = SSHKit.config.formatter.new($stdout) causes it to blow up at the moment because the formatter method is now a private method. So either the docs need updating or there's another way to do it...

Comment: I looked through open issues and don't see anything similiar, but `SSHKit.config.formatter` is definitely private so you may try opening a new issue. Also - looking at number of open issues (and repeating ones) I wouldn't consider this gem very reliable.

Comment: Can you try adding this in config? `SSHKit.config.formatter = :pretty`

Comment: Hi Michael, adding that produces undefined method `formatter=' for #<SSHKit::Configuration:0x0000000597e1e0>

Comment: ah, it should be SSHKit.config.format = :pretty - but that is actually the default behaviour anyway so no real change.

Comment: Thanks for your help though Michael. I'd have probably given up had you not kept suggesting things....

Comment: Great you solved that! You can get extra karma for opening pull request with updated README on github! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

What I actually needed to do was change the output_verbosity to :debug in order for it to show the puts statement in the second rake task:

```
SSHKit.config.output_verbosity = :debug

rake sshkit_hello
=>  INFO [6dd1bbf7] Running bundle exec rake hello on 
=> DEBUG [6dd1bbf7] Command: bundle exec rake hello
=> DEBUG [6dd1bbf7]     Hello World!
=>  INFO [6dd1bbf7] Finished in 6.596 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```